# What is the function of 国家副主席 in China?

Tags: culture

If this is the counterpart of Vice President of the US, it doesn't have the same function as the head of the congress. And in the similar case, there is no vice secretary general of the ruling Communist party's central committee, but at other levels vice secretary is provided.

Does 国家副主席 only serve as a spare for the President that was called chairman in Mao's day?

Comment: Is this on-topic here (it doesn't seem language-related)?  It's definitely [on-topic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) at [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/); maybe this question should be migrated.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Please note that I mark this question as one of culture, which can not be separated from the language it is presented.  Oxford and Cambridge also publish their own dictionaries of culture to help English language learners understand the language better, for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Per Wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vice_President_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China):

"The vice president's duties include assisting the President, and replacing him should he resign or die in office. In reality the position of the vice president is mostly ceremonial."

"The vice president may play a major role in foreign affairs. For instance, the vice president generally sits on the Foreign Affairs Leading Group, a policy coordination body of the CCP. The vice president has also typically sits on the Central Coordination Group for Hong Kong and Macau Affairs. Therefore, while the vice president may not actually have substantive powers as defined in the Constitution, the office nonetheless carries significance and prestige. The holders of the office have all been individuals with a degree of political clout."

Comment: On theory, the position of the president is also ceremonial.

Comment: @wznmickey Quite true. But he is also usually the leader of the CCP, which holds the power.